# Qualtrics: Automatic blinking cursor (focus) does not work on JFE, only on SE surveybuilder

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

This has been an ongoing issue for me with my Qualtrics survey, where I need an automatic blinking cursor to appear in a textbox as soon as the page/question appears. It works flawlessly using Qualtrics' SE survey builder, but it does not work properly on JFE. Qualtrics could not help me with the issue, and would revert my surveys back to SE, but now they will no longer revert it back to SE so I need to solve this issue.

My code is as follows

```
$("QR~2_QID1").select();
```

This also works on SE

```
document.getElementById("QR~QID1").select();
```

And this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myTextInput');

input.select();
```

When I use the same code with a JFE survey, it appears to work in the preview, where a blinking cursor appears on the mobile side, but I am still able to type and have the text appear on the desktop side. However, when using the actual survey link, no cursor appears, and I am not able to type unless I click the textbox (which I want to avoid).

I believe the issue has something to do with mobile compatibility. The SE survey preview does not include a mobile version, and it might be that the code on the JFE version is defaulting to mobile for some reason (we are excluding mobile users for our research). I wonder if there is a way to turn off mobile compatibility in JFE.

Something else that I noticed, is that when I create a new survey, and include a textbox with the code on the first page, it actually works properly. However, if I put a multiple choice question on the first page with a page break, the textbox no longer has a blinking cursor on the second page.

Comment: I think you are looking for .focus() instead .select()

Comment: @MFGSparka .focus doesn't seem to work, it also didn't work initially in the SE survey builder.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in jfe to focus on the first text input in a question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $(this.questionId).down('.InputText').focus();
});
```

EDIT:
Deferring execution might help with conflicts either with page transition or other scripts:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $(this.questionId).down('.InputText').focus().defer();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My first question ID that I was testing is QR~QID449. When I replaced that with "questionId", I recieved an alert that said the "~" was an unexpected token. I added single and double quotes around the ID, which allowed me to input it, but the focus still didn't work. I also tried just the code as you provided it (using questionId), with no luck. When it worked for you, was it the first question/first page of the survey? My previous code seems to work in that instance, but not when it's later on.

Comment: You should avoid using hard coded question ids.  Do it exactly as I did above.  Also, under Look & Feel set Page Transition to None (this should be done anytime you are using custom JavaScript). Once you turn that off, it will work for any page/position.  Of course, you can only focus on one field per page.

Comment: Could you explain hard coded question ids? How would I avoid them? I've followed your steps and it's still not working. I copied and pasted your code into mine, and made sure to turn page transition to off. I just don't understand why it works perfectly in SE, but not JFE for me.

Comment: I understand what you meant by hard coded IDs now. Your code does work in the survey preview, and question preview. However, I still cannot get it to work when using the distribution link and taking the survey as if I were a participant. It only works if the text input question is the first in the survey, otherwise there's no blinking cursor nor am I able to start typing and have the text show up. The only time it works when using the distribution link is if the text input is the first question of the survey (not even first on the page works if it's on a subsequent page).

Comment: Works fine for me, so I'm not sure what your issue is. Maybe other scripts running of the same page. Try deferring it as shown in the edited answer above.

Comment: Unfortunately, deferring doesn't help either. I made a new survey that only has 3 questions on 3 separate pages. The first question/page has text entry with the above code and the focus does work. The 2nd page/question has a multiple choice question, and the 3rd question/page has another text entry with your code, and it doesn't work on the 3rd page. I also have transition set to none. There's no other code so I'm not sure why it's not working. I also changed the template to see if that was the issue, but still didn't help.

Comment: After further testing it appears to work in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Internet Explorer out of the browsers I've tested so far.