# Qualtrics Javascript focus / select / place cursor on text box when page loads

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to make Qualtrics focus automatically on a text box (single question per page) so participants can start typing right away.

I have tried different things from other answers (e.g.,[Qualtrics: Automatic blinking cursor (focus) does not work on JFE, only on SE surveybuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889061/qualtrics-automatic-blinking-cursor-focus-does-not-work-on-jfe-only-on-se-su)) but the focusing doesn't work on browsers like IE (Firefox, without including code, automatically focuses on the question).

The code also seems to invalidate code for advancing to next page by pressing "Enter" (below), so the survey gets stuck on the page

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
 this.hideNextButton();
 this.hidePreviousButton();
 var that = this;
 Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
   case 13: // 'enter' was pressed
    choiceID = 1;
    break;
  }

  if (choiceID) {
   Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
   that.clickNextButton();
  }
 });
});
```

Any ideas how to fix this? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code may be hideNextButton with addOnload due to timing issues. Use addOnReady instead. Also, it is best to check for the existence of the PreviousButton first.  If is is not there it will cause an error and stop your script. On some browsers you have to select a field before you can focus on it, activate() does that.  Finally, it is better to add your event handler to the text field, instead of the document.

Try this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
 $('NextButton').hide();
 if($('PreviousButton')) $('PreviousButton').hide();
 var inputText = $(this.questionId).down('.InputText');
 var evt = inputText.on('keydown', function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13) {
     evt.stop();    
     $('NextButton').click();
   }
 });
 inputText.activate();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works. I will say however, that when I tried just clearing all the previous Javascript and inserting this into the preexisting survey I was working with, it didn't work. I had to create a new survey for it to work.. not sure why Qualtrics does that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to have the cursor placed in the first text box, say for a form field in Qualtrics? I need people to input their contact information (street address, city, state etc.) and I'd like the cursor to be automatically placed in the top box. I can do it with single questions but haven't figured out how to do it with the form field.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ebony, this looks like a question rather than an answer, please ask this as a separate question

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32937796)